# Remove character from string if its not in a list...?

Tags: python, string

I have been using .translate() but I would like to remove a character from a string if it is not one of the characters in the list.  I don't think I'm using "not" correctly, but that was mainly to show what I mean (sorry, bad way, I know). The string is

```
MDVFMKGLSKAKEGVVAAAEKTKQGVAEAAGKTKEGVLYVGSKTKEGVVHGVATVAEKTKEQVTNVGGAVVTGVTAVAQKTVEGAGSIAAATGFVKKDQLGKNEEGAXPQEGILEDMPVDPDNEAYEMPSEEGYQDYEPEAXX
```

and I am trying to remove the Xs.

```
aminoacids = ['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y']
contentjoined.translate(None, not(aminoacids))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get missed characters :

```
>>> contentjoined.translate(None,''.join([i for i in contentjoined if i not in aminoacids]))
'MDVFMKGLSKAKEGVVAAAEKTKQGVAEAAGKTKEGVLYVGSKTKEGVVHGVATVAEKTKEQVTNVGGAVVTGVTAVAQKTVEGAGSIAAATGFVKKDQLGKNEEGAPQEGILEDMPVDPDNEAYEMPSEEGYQDYEPEA'
>>>
```

Or you can use `set.difference` :

```
contentjoined.translate(None,''.join(set(contentjoined).difference(aminoacids)))
'MDVFMKGLSKAKEGVVAAAEKTKQGVAEAAGKTKEGVLYVGSKTKEGVVHGVATVAEKTKEQVTNVGGAVVTGVTAVAQKTVEGAGSIAAATGFVKKDQLGKNEEGAPQEGILEDMPVDPDNEAYEMPSEEGYQDYEPEA'
>>>
```

But you can do this job with a simple list comprehension and `join` :

```
>>> ''.join([i for i in contentjoined if i in aminoacids])
'MDVFMKGLSKAKEGVVAAAEKTKQGVAEAAGKTKEGVLYVGSKTKEGVVHGVATVAEKTKEQVTNVGGAVVTGVTAVAQKTVEGAGSIAAATGFVKKDQLGKNEEGAPQEGILEDMPVDPDNEAYEMPSEEGYQDYEPEA'
>>>
```

Comment: Why the extra translate step? Isn't `''.join([i for i in contentjoined if i in aminoacids])` enough?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Did you have tried that code??? it just returns 'XXX' You should remove the `not`

Comment: Yes both work. I personally prefer to use set.difference... Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yeah I was thinking about that! but you remind it before my edit ;)

Comment: You don't need it as a list comprehension either.  The generator itself is good enough, as `join` only needs an iterable: `''.join(i for i in contentjoined if i in aminoacids)`.  You should only use a list comprehension if you explicitly need it as a list (ie. you want to specifically pass it as a list or want to use a list method or operation on it).  If you just need an iterable (which join needs), use a generator to save on constructing a superfluous list, and to express the same thing with fewer characters.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you're using `translate()` instead of `strip()`?

If you know there's a specific character you're looking to remove, `strip()` is a much easier way:

```
long_string = "MDVFMKGLSKAKEGVVAAAEKTKQGVAEAAGKTKEGVLYVGSKTKEGVVHGVATVAEKTKEQVTNVGGAVVTGVTAVAQKTVEGAGSIAAATGFVKKDQLGKNEEGAXPQEGILEDMPVDPDNEAYEMPSEEGYQDYEPEAXX" 
print long_string.strip('X')
```

Output: `MDVFMKGLSKAKEGVVAAAEKTKQGVAEAAGKTKEGVLYVGSKTKEGVVHGVATVAEKTKEQVTNVGGAVVTGVTAVAQKTVEGAGSIAAATGFVKKDQLGKNEEGAXPQEGILEDMPVDPDNEAYEMPSEEGYQDYEPEA`

Comment: Guess I just conveniently missed the "not on the list" aspect.

Comment: Yes is there a simple way to use strip for lists..? I didn't think there was so I used translate, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I still think it would be better, however, to figure out which is the missing amino acid and use `strip` instead of comparing each character to a list.  If that chain becomes very long, that's a lot of processing time wasted.

Comment: No, there's no strip for lists, but figuring out which is amino acid you want to remove from the chain beforehand will probably be easier to read and process.  Just food for thought.

Comment: Fair point. But is there a way to figure out which character is not an amino acid other than comparing each character to a list? I guess it could take a long time if the string/file is big...

Answer (score -1):

Not a fancy solution, but you can try adding the characters to a new string if it's on the list

```
newString = ""
for i in range(len(oldString)):
  if oldString[i] in aminoacids:
    newString += oldString[i]
```